# How to not insert a space at both side of '<' and '>'?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I get a formatting mistake that when I just have formatted my ts code with [Beautify Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) in VS Code, any types `Array<T>` and `Map<T1, T2>` will be formatted as `Array < T >` and `Map < T1, T2 >`. So I have to delete the space manually.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

**Before formatting:**

[image: Before formatting]

**After formatting:**

[image: After formatting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`js-beautify` doesn't officially support TypeScript (see [this open issue](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/555) tracking the extra whitespace around generic type parameters). You'll probably have more luck in general with a formatter that officially supports TS, such as [prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode).

Comment: thanks a lot. ive almost forgot this question : )